How to Enforce Context-Only Responses in a Conversational Retrieval Chain with LangChain and OpenAI GPT-4?
I'm working on a Django project where I need to create a conversational retrieval system using LangChain with OpenAI's GPT-4 model. The goal is to ensure that the model only answers questions based on the provided document context. If the relevant information is not in the context, the model should respond with a message indicating the lack of access to relevant files.
here is a simplified version of my setup
from langchain.chains import ConversationalRetrievalChain
from langchain_community.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain_huggingface.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain_community.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.schema import Document

embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name="sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2")
chroma_db = Chroma(embeddings=embeddings, collection_name="AEM_Responses")

def handle_query_flow(chroma_db, email):
    system_prompt = """You are an AI system that answers questions based on documents. 
                    Answer only using the provided context. If the information is not in the context, 
                    respond with: 'User does not have access to any relevant files. 
                    Please provide more context or check your access permissions.' 
                    Do not search outside the given context. Do not use any outside knowledge or 
                    provide an answer from your own training data. Only use the provided context.
                    If you get empty context then just say that this user does not have access to any files.
                    """

    chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
        ChatOpenAI(temperature=0.0, model_name='gpt-4-turbo'),
        chroma_db.as_retriever(search_kwargs={'filter': {'email': email}}),
        memory=None
    )

    chat_history = []

    while True:
        query = input("Please enter your query (type 'quit' to exit): ").strip()
        if query.lower() == 'quit':
            break

        retriever = chroma_db.as_retriever(search_kwargs={'filter': {'email': email}})
        retrieved_docs = retriever.get_relevant_documents(query)
        count_retrieved_docs = len(retrieved_docs)
        
        response = chain.invoke({'question': query, 'system_prompt': system_prompt, 'chat_history': chat_history})
        answer = response.get('answer', '')
        print(f"Answer: {answer}")
        print("CONTEXT DOCUMENTS")
        print(retrieved_docs)

    return JsonResponse({"message": "Query session ended"}, status=200) ```





Problem:
Despite setting up a system prompt and the ConversationalRetrievalChain, the model sometimes provides answers based on general knowledge instead of strictly using the provided context. For instance, when a user with no relevant documents in context asks a question, the model still responds with an answer rather than indicating the absence of relevant documents.

What I've Tried:

System Prompt: I've clearly stated that the model should not use outside knowledge and should only answer based on the provided context.
Checking Retrieved Documents: Before generating a response, I check if any meaningful documents are retrieved.
Questions:

How can I ensure that the model strictly adheres to the provided context and does not use any outside knowledge?
Is there a way to programmatically enforce this restriction, ensuring that if no relevant context is found, the model responds with a predefined message?
Are there any best practices or specific configurations in LangChain or with OpenAI models that I might be missing?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

